# Recreate ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin## user as [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis

During an install of SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 3 we received the following error:

Error: 15151, Severity: 16, State: 1.

Cannot find the user '##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.

Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'SSIS_hotfix_install.sql' encountered error 15151, state 1, severity 16.

On the instance there is the SQL login [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##]

On the SSISDB database there is a SQL user linked to this login called [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##] Created the day after the login.

The SSISDB user should be [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] and created at the same time as the login.

The solution appears to be to drop the [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##] user and create the correct [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] user.

```
USE [SSISDB]
GO
DROP USER [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##]
GO

USE [SSISDB]
GO
CREATE USER [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] FOR LOGIN [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##]
GO
USE [SSISDB]
GO
ALTER USER [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Can anyone see any problems arising from dropping and recreating the SSISDB user?

This is a production instance. All test instances have the login and user configured correctly so the service pack installed successfully.

Many Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution will work. Don't forget to grant permissions:

```
USE [SSISDB]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [internal].[cleanup_server_project_version] TO [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [internal].[cleanup_server_retention_window] TO [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. The following script helped me, based on [this](https://amitelman.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/mssql-service-cannot-start-after-security-update-for-sql-server-2019-rtm-cu-kb4583459/) and [this](https://www.sqlservice.se/script-level-upgrade-for-database-master-failed/) blog posts.

```sql
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##] WITH PASSWORD='Pa$$w0rd', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##
GO

USE [SSISDB]
GO
CREATE USER [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] FOR LOGIN [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

But first you need to run the following command in CMD to start SQL Server  instance.

```
net start MSSQLSERVER /T902
```

-or-

```
net start MSSQL$instancename /T902
```